# Perl : Picking a varying filename with a specific extension from a specific folder

Tags: regex, xml, perl

Problem: I have a specific folder in which i have only one file with a specific extension. This file is generated one and the name always varies...

I want to assign it to a variable and then pass to subroutine in perl
i tried as follows

my $file = "./abc/def/*.xml"; 
and also tried using one field on which i have control

my $file = "./abc/def/*._${username}_.*.xml";

but i print the file name.... it says *.xml or *._name_.*.xml instead of the actual filename ...

Can someone tell me how to solve my problem.
I am new to perl...so any help here will be great.
I have searched few other places but couldn't find anything for this specific point.

Comment: my $file = "./abc/def/*._${username}_.*.xml"; for example...filename is something like temp_username_date timestamp.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `glob`:

```
my $file = glob './abc/def/*.xml';
```

Or perhaps:

```
my @files = glob './abc/def/*.xml';
```

Not sure why you're having problems with the `$username` part though. It *should* expand that var. (although, I don't know why you have `_` either side).

Comment: Thanks Sobrique. glob was the one i was looking for. This perfectly solves my problem. i am using $file as i always will have only one file in this folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can print your files using the bellow way.Then you can use them.

Code:

```
    my @dir = `ls ./abc/def/`;
    foreach my $id (@dir)
    {
            chomp($id);
            print "$id\n";
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It's a horrible idea to call `ls` from within `perl`.

Comment: Thanks Arjit for your response

Comment: Thanks for you code and suggestion. I was not aware of **glob** function. So I found this way to solve this problem.@Sobrique